# Regex: Excluding combinations of characters and limiting certain characters in Regex / jQuery (partly working)

Tags: jquery, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am trying to validate an email input using Regex in jQuery - only for the following criteria:

**Inputs I want to allow:**

- lowercase letters (multiple)
- digits (multiple)
- dots / periods (multiple)
- dashes (multiple)
- @ sign (only one)

**Inputs I want to prevent:**

- dot / period, dash, @ sign at the beginning of the string
- dot / period, dash, @ sign at the end of the string
- two dots / periods OR two dashes in a row
- a dot / period and a dash (or a dash and a dot / period) in a row

So far I came up with the following but I am having trouble with excluding the combinations of two symbols and with limiting the @ sign to only one.

Can someone show me how to do this right ?

**Note:**
I am only looking for a basic validation for the above criteria and for English letters only (everything else I cover in jQuery).

**My Regex:**

```
var val = $(this).val();
var checkEmail = /(?!^[@.-])(?!.*@@)(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*--)(?!.*[@.-]$)[0-9a-z@\.\-]/g;

if(val.match(checkEmail) {
   console.log('input valid');
   } else {
   console.log('input invalid');
}
```

Many thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/IOzcb7/1) help?

Comment: @Mandy8055: That looks great - thanks a lot ! Will test it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex below to achieve your results:

```
^(?!.+?(?:\.-|\.\.|--|-@|\.@|@\.).+?)[^.-@ ][a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9_.-]+(?<=[^.-@ ])$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`^, $`** - Represents start and end of test string resp.
>
> **`(?!.+?(?:\.-|\.\.|--|-@|\.@|@\.).+?)`** - Represents **negative lookahead** not matching the test string if it contains consecutive **`.-`**, **`..`**, **`--`**, **`-@`**, **`.@`** or **`@.`**.
>
> **`[^.-@ ]`** - Represents negative match if string starts with any of **`.-@`**.
>
> **`[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9_.-]+`** - Represents the character set where the String contains anything in the characters mentioned above with only one `@` sign.
>
> **`(?<=[^.-@ ])`** - Represents positive lookbehind which matches any test string not ending with **`.-@`**.

You can find the demo of above regex [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/IOzcb7/4)

**IMPLEMENTATION IN JAVASCRIPT(JQUERY):**

```js
var val = "hello@gmail.com";
var checkEmail = /^(?!.+?(?:\.-|\.\.|--|-@|\.@|@\.).+?)[^.-@ ][a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9_.-]+(?<=[^.-@ ])$/gm;

if (val.match(checkEmail)) {
  console.log('input valid');
} else {
  console.log('input invalid');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```